# Volume of the convex polyhedron in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ defined by $|x_{1} + x_{2} + \ldots + x_{n} | \leq 1$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, euclidean-geometry, volume

I wanted to calculate volume of the set

$$S_{d}:= \{ x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots, x_{d} : |x_{i}| \leq 1 \text{ for each } 1 \leq i \leq d \text{ and } |x_{1} + x_{2} + \cdots + x_{d}| \leq 1\}.$$

Is it possible to calculate these for any value of $n$? I suspect one has to use calculus, but I am failing to see a solution for a while now.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, that is *not* a square in the case $n=2$.

Comment: It would be a square if you had $|x_1|+|x_2|\leq1$, but yours is shaped like a pill.

Comment: Uhh.. I see.. Thanks.. then I don't have it for $n = 2$ either. I have edited it to show that.

Comment: $S_2$ is a square minus two triangles.  $S_3$ is a cube minus two tetrahedra(a.k.a., triangular pyramids).  $S_4$ is a hypercube minus two pentachora. Et c.

Comment: if you restrict each variable to be in $[0,1]$ I think the volume works out to be $V = \frac 1{d!}$ , you might be able to use this to come up with some sort of combinatoric solution

Comment: @WW1 The convex solid in question is symmetric about the origin. That might help calculate the volume if you could give me some more hint into calculation of volume when we restrict the variables to $[0,1]$.

Comment: with all $x_i$ in $[0,1]$ and $k \leq 1$
$$ V \left [\left (\sum_{i=1}^nx_i    \right )<k\right ]   =  k^n   \;\;V \left [ \left (\sum_{i=1}^nx_i    \right )<1\right ]  $$
(it's just a re-scaling of the axes.) and ..
$$  V \left [\left (\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}x_i    \right )<1\right ]  = \int _0^1  V \left [\left (\sum_{i=1}^nx_i    \right )<k\right ]    dk $$

so

$$  V \left [\left (\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}x_i    \right )<1\right ]    = V \left [\left (\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i    \right )<1\right ] \int _0^1 k^n \; dk $$

Comment: I thought real hard and long about this for a while... trying to see if Volume of the set $S_{d} \longrightarrow 2^{d}$? I think it does but again.. it seems as hard as calculating the volume itself.